# Using MultipleChoiceField in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have been going through the documentation over and again. It says, i have to import django.forms to use multiple choice widget. I am confused, if I am defining League as Model, and want to choose DAY_CHOICES as multiplechoicefield, how would i go about doing it. Can i define calls forms inside a Model class?

For better understanding of my query, here is my models.py

```
class League(models.Model):
    DAY_CHOICES = (
        ('MO', 'Monday'),
        ('TU', 'Tueday'),
        ('WE', 'Wednesday'),
        ('TH', 'Thursday'),
        ('FR', 'Friday'),
        ('SA', 'Saturday'),
        ('SU', 'Sunday'),
    )

    SEASON_STATUS = (
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('Concluded', 'Concluded')
    )

    LEAGUE_TYPE = (
        ('Home', 'Home League'),
        ('Away', 'Home and Away League'),
        ('Cup', 'Cup'),
        ('CupAway', 'Cup, Home and Away'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    league_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=LEAGUE_TYPE, default='Away')
    play_days = models.CharField(max_length=28, choices=DAY_CHOICES, default='SU')
    #defining rules for winning and loosing
    win = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    loss = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    draw = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SEASON_STATUS, default='In Progress')
```

//mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different things that you really don't want to get confused in Django:

- Model fields
- Form fields
- Form widgets

The model field controls what goes into the database, and when using the automatic form creation features, the model field type will give you a form containing a certain form field.

The form widgets control the HTML that the user interacts with in the form. For some form field types there might be more than one widget that could work (i.e. the time & date widgets admin uses versus the ones that are normally in user created forms).

Once you get this distinction clear in your mind then much of the documentation should make a lot more sense.

Comment: _The model field controls what goes into the database, and when using the automatic form creation features, the model field type will give you a form containing a certain form field_ < This confuses me @KayESS. According to this, first i need to create a seperate model, containing choices. create a form to call that choices. and then i would be able to call this form in my main Model. Right?

Comment: When you ask Django for a form from the model it chooses which form fields to use based on the model fields. This is also how admin works. So the choices you put into the model are the only ones that can go into the database. Django will create a form for you with the same choices, but this time in a form field rather than a model field.

Answer (score 0):

You do not configure forms within your models.py file. Your models.py file looks fine. Forms, and the widgets used to represent individual fields within those forms, are generally defined in a forms.py file. Look over the documentation on [creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) as well as the documentation on [customizing the display of models within the Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) interface (assuming you're making this form available through that interface).

Comment: exactly, i want the admin to be able to select multiple playday choices.

Answer (score 0):

typically a `charField` with `choices` is used to store a *single* choice.

Say you choose Sunday and Monday. What would you like to store in `play_days`? Some kind of serialisation, e.g. "SU, MO"? Then you need to tell django how to serialise the data. Also, this is probably a **bad idea**, as it makes it difficult to query the data.

**Instead**, consider making a new class to hold days, and changing `play_days` to a [many to many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). As a bonus, m2m fields have a multiple choice widget by default

Comment: i am using rrule in [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) to calculate the fixtures, using a custom function that i wrote earlier. so i would want SU,MO to be a comma seperated value in django db. it would make my life a lot easier in the long run :)